SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from <LINK>
I need help with this code I'm writing for GNRE in Espirito Santo, using the SOAP standard (version 1.2), I'm programming in PHP (version 7.2.24), and it's giving this error: SOAP Error: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL : Couldn't load from 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/' : failed to load external entity "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" follows the code:
<?php

class DuaePdfClient {
    private $arqCertificado;
    private $senhaCertificado;
    private $wsdl = 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/';
    //private $wsdl = 'https://app.sefaz.es.gov.br/WsDua/DuaService.asmx';
    private $versao = '1.01';
    private $namespace = 'http://www.sefaz.es.gov.br/duae/wsdl/DuaObterPdf';

    public function __construct($arqCertificado, $senhaCertificado) {
        if (!extension_loaded('soap')) {
            throw new Exception("Extensao SOAP nao esta instalada");
        }
        if (!extension_loaded('openssl')) {
            throw new Exception("Extensao OpenSSL nao esta instalada");
        }

        $this->arqCertificado = $arqCertificado;
        $this->senhaCertificado = $senhaCertificado;
    }

    public function obterPdf($arqXml) {
        try {
            if (!file_exists($arqXml)) {
                throw new Exception("Arquivo XML nao encontrado: $arqXml");
            }

            // Le o conteudo do XML
            $xmlContent = file_get_contents($arqXml);
            if ($xmlContent === false) {
                throw new Exception("Erro ao ler arquivo XML");
            }

            // Configuracoes do contexto SSL
            $contextOptions = [
                'ssl' => [
                    'verify_peer' => false,
                    'verify_peer_name' => false,
                    'allow_self_signed' => true
                ]
            ];

            // Configuracoes do SOAP
            $soapOptions = [
                'local_cert' => $this->arqCertificado,
                'passphrase' => $this->senhaCertificado,
                'trace' => 1,
                'exceptions' => true,
                'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
                'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
                'stream_context' => stream_context_create($contextOptions)
             ];

            $client = new SoapClient($this->wsdl, $soapOptions);

            $header = new SoapHeader(
                $this->namespace,
                'duaServiceHeader',
                ['versao' => $this->versao]
            );

            $client->__setSoapHeaders($header);

            // Prepara os parametros
            $params = [
                'duaDadosMsg' => [
                    'obterPdfDua' => [
                        'versao' => $this->versao,
                        'xml' => $xmlContent
                    ]
                  ]
            ];

            // Faz a chamada do servico
            $response = $client->duaObterPdf($params);

            if (isset($response->duaObterPdfResult)) {
                $pdfContent = base64_decode($response->duaObterPdfResult->pdf);

                if ($pdfContent === false) {
                    throw new Exception("Erro ao decodificar PDF");
                }

                return $pdfContent;
            }

            throw new Exception("Resposta invalida do servico");
        } catch (SoapFault $e) {
            throw new Exception("Erro SOAP: " . $e->getMessage());
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}

$nrParam = count($_SERVER["argv"]) - 1;

if($nrParam < 1) {
    echo "E01 Nao ha parametros para execucao";
    return;
}

$acao= $_SERVER["argv"][1];

if($acao == 'emissao') {
    if($nrParam < 5) {
        echo "E01 Sao necessarios cinco parametros para execucao";
                                                                                                                                                       
  return;
    }

    $arqXml = $argv[2];

    $arqCertificado = $argv[3];

    if(substr($arqCertificado, 0, 2) == "..") {
        $arqCertificado = "/var/www".substr($arqCertificado, 2);
    }

    $arqCertificado = str_replace("//", "/", $arqCertificado);

    $senhaCertificado = $argv[4];

    $tipoAmbiente = $argv[5];
} else if($acao == 'pdf') {
    if($nrParam < 7) {
        echo "E01 Sao necessarios sete parametros para execucao";
        return;
    }

    try {
        $nrDUA = $argv[2];

        $arqCertificado = $argv[3];

        if(substr($arqCertificado, 0, 2) == "..") {
            $arqCertificado = "/var/www".substr($arqCertificado, 2);
        }

        $arqCertificado = str_replace("//", "/", $arqCertificado);

        if (!file_exists($arqCertificado)) {
            throw new Exception("Arquivo certificado nao encontrado: $arqCertificado");
        }
        $arqCertificado = str_replace("//", "/", $arqCertificado);

        if (!file_exists($arqCertificado)) {
            throw new Exception("Arquivo certificado nao encontrado: $arqCertificado");
        }

        $senhaCertificado = $argv[4];

        $tipoAmbiente = $argv[5];

        $caminho = $argv[6];

        if ($caminho == "/") {
            $caminhoArq = "/var/www/html/files".$caminho;
        } else {
            $caminhoArq = "/var/www/html/files/".$caminho;
        }

        $arqXml = $caminhoArq.$argv[7];

        if (!file_exists($arqXml)) {
            throw new Exception("Arquivo XML nao encontrado: $arqXml");
        }

        $caminhoArq = "/var/www/html/files".$caminho;

        // Cria instancia do cliente
        $client = new DuaePdfClient($arqCertificado, $senhaCertificado);

        // Obtem o PDF
        $pdfContent = $client->obterPdf($arqXml);

        // Gera nome do arquivo de saida
// Salva o PDF
        if (file_put_contents($outputFile, $pdfContent) === false) {
            throw new Exception("Erro ao salvar arquivo PDF");
        }

        echo "PDF gerado com sucesso: $outputFile\n";
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        die("Erro: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n");
    }
} else {
    echo "E01 Acao ".$acao." invalida para execucao";
    return;
}


http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/ is clearly not the correct WSDL file for your service.
